# HTML form sending date and time in 01-23-2018 9:17 AM format

Tags: html, forms

I have been creating HTML forms for our office, but have gotten stuck on a seemingly very simple task. The client have requested to send them the appointment date and time in format: Example: 01-23-2018 9:17 AM,
     I tried to paste this code in w3school site and when i run it it takes the time and date in the format: mm/dd/yyyy hr min am/pm . but the server always shows the out put in a different format, such as: Appointment_Date=2018-03-06T12:59 
     I have tried to read though different forums but haven't been able to implement it so that I get the format what my client desires. thanks in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Form</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <div>
      <label for="Appointment Date"><font color="red">Appointment Date*:</font></label>
      <input type=datetime-local id="Appointment Date" name="Appointment_Date" mydate="Appointment_Date" required>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Date/Time values can be displayed in all sorts of ways, but there are some standard ways of storing them.

Even though your input allows the user to enter a date/time in the `01-23-2018 9:17 AM` format, when it submits to the server it's actually sending a string in the `2018-01-23T09:17` format. It's important to understand that you're still sending the exact same value that the user entered, even though it's in a different format.

Once your server has that date/time, it can choose to display it however it wants to.

If your server is running PHP, this will help you output the date in the format you want: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

If your server is running Node.js, moment.js is a great library for dealing with date/time values: https://momentjs.com/docs/

If your server is something else, I'd recommend looking up documentation around how to format dates for that particular technology.

Answer (score 0):

Well this worked for me,  tag with class="dateinput" , gives the user option to type the date and time manually and in the format requested by them.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>HTML Forms</h2>

<form action="/action_page.php">
<div>
    <label for="Appointment Date"><font color="red">Appointment Date*:</font></label>
    Appointment Date (Example: 6-23-2009 9:17 AM):<span class="dateInput"><input  id="00N0V000009O81z" name="00N0V000009O81z" size="20" type="text" /></span><br>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form> 

<p>If you click the "Submit" button, the form-data will be sent to a page called "/action_page.php".</p>

</body>
</html>
```